# How can I move a ball to a specific direction in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logic, physics

Could someone tell me how can I move the ball to  the arrow trajectory? 
Here is my code, I can't find how to add the force to move the ball with the arrow trajectory, please help me.

```
//private attributes
private Rigidbody2D ball;
private float rotationZ;


// Use this for initialization
void Start() {
    ball = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

public void SetCanChooseDirection() {
    //this is the code that allows the arrow to rotate around the ball and it is perfectly working
    Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    difference.Normalize();

    rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(-difference.y, -difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotationZ);
}

public void Launch(float force) {
    //and here I should put the code that allows the ball to move with the arrow trajectory but, please help me
    Vector2 direction = ??????;
    ball.AddForce(???????);
}
```

[I need to throw the ball in the arrow's trajectory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmCpv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the velocity command, for example:

```
ball.velocity = new Vector2(0.0f, 2.0f);
```

My advice is to always check the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html).